# How much connections is allowed in azure service Eventhub.

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

- I am using Eventhub and i want to connect million of devices with
  eventhub. My Scenario is one stream analytic is reading data from
  eventhub or some receiver application is also running.But when
  connection goes greater then 5 some receiver application
  stopped(Error:not more then 5 connections is allowed on same consumer
  group).After some R&D i have set the epoch, same for all the receiver
  ,so by doing this not any error occurred.so my question is setting
  same epoch with all receiver we can create how much connections or if
  5 connection is limit of eventhub so how can i read million of
  devices data.
- **second Question** is what epoch is set by stream analytic and how can i know which epoch is set by which stream analytic so that when
  my receiver service is up so connection will always gain by these
  application not stream analytic,**(by setting higher values to receiver application)**.
- How much connection is allowed for sending Data on eventhub and how
  much receiver connection is allowed on eventhub.

Comment: Each stream processor will need its own dedicated consumer group in the Event Hub since each Stream Processor will take up 5x dedicated readers and writers from that Event Hub. Each consumer group will be allocated their own readers and writers.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by epoch?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK each job has only one consumer group and stream analytics creates receivers without epochs.

Regarding the max number of connections you can see on the official pricing page : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

Of course the connections number is valid for senders and receivers.

Paolo

Comment: Thanks Palao for response,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee732538.aspx as per this link only 5000 connection allowed on namespace and namespace is parent of service bus it means i can't create more then 5000 connection on topic/subscription/and eventhub. if this is the limit so how can million of devices communicate with service bus at one particular time .

Comment: The documentation is misleading but Event Hubs has another price quotas you can see the links I provided you